# Select all or few tables in Access DB files and stored it at sql server

Tags: php, sql-server, database, ms-access, yii2

currently i'm developing a system using yii2 framework. In my modules i have to upload an Access DB file to the sql server and extract the data to a multiples table. Right now i can upload access file, but only can extract one table by calling its name (refer to the 1st code below). But i have multiple tables So, the questions is, how do i extract multiple tables from access db file without calling the tables name?
[here is the image of tables inside an access file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUl6f.jpg)

and this my code to upload and save the access file to sql server and call table 'hs2_13'

```
if($data->save())
        {

          Yii::$app->session->setFlash('msg', 'Successful upload File and Process Integration will be Execute');
          Yii::$app->session->setFlash('msg_process', 'Process Integration in Execute');
          $result = $this->actionReadAccess($data,'"hs2_13"');
         return $this->refresh();
        }
```

and this is the function to read from sql server and extract the table.

```
public function actionReadAccess($data, $table)
{
  $query = 'SELECT TOP 100  * FROM ' . $table;

  $path = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]. Yii::$app->request->baseurl."/".$data->path;
  $uname = explode(" ",php_uname());
  $os = $uname[0];
  switch ($os){
    case 'Windows':
    $driver = '{Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}';
    break;
    case 'Linux':
    $driver = 'MDBTools';
    break;
    default:
    exit("Don't know about this OS");
  }
  $dataSourceName = "odbc:Driver=$driver;DBQ=$path;";

  $connection = new \PDO($dataSourceName);
  $result = $connection->query($query)->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  print_r($result);
  die();
  return $result;
}
```

right now i want to call all tables inside access file and extract the data. and the data later will be save inside new table at sql-server. i hope you can understand my questions and sorry for my bad english. Thank you.

Comment: Can't fetch the tables name dynamically from access db file from php?

Comment: The MDBTools come with a tool called mdb-tables which gives you a listing of all Access Tables in a file. In Windows you can list the tables via tabledef. Another approach could be to have a table in the accessDB (that could even be automatically updated via VBA when someone alters the AccessDB) that contains all the tablenames - then you would only have to know the name of that table.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a [COM interface](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.com.php) to loop through the MS Access database's [TableDefs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195790.aspx) collection to add table names into an array. Add below new function to your class as a new method which returns a string array of all current table names. Then loop through tables during querying process.

Please note this solution requires MSAccess.exe (MS Office program) installed on machine running script via a PHP installation on Windows (usually COM Library ships with Windows install but might need a .dll add-on or enabled extension in .ini file).

**New Function**

```
public function getaccTables($database) {                               
    $tables = [];

    try {
       $acc =  new COM("Access.Application", NULL, CP_UTF8) 
                          or Die ("Did not instantiate Access");
       $acc->OpenCurrentDatabase($database);               
       $db = $acc->CurrentDb();

       foreach ($db->TableDefs as $tbl){
          // IGNORE SYSTEM AND TEMP TABLES
          if (substr($tbl->Name(), 0, 4) != 'MSys' && substr($tbl->Name(), 0, 1) != '~') {
              $tables[] = $tbl->Name();
          }
       }
    }            

    catch (com_exception $e){
        echo $e;
    }

    $acc->DoCmd->CloseDatabase();
    $acc->Quit();

    // RELEASE RESOURCES
    $db = NULL; unset($db);        
    $acc = NULL; unset($acc);

    return $tables;
}
```

**Updated functions**

```
if($data->save()) {

    Yii::$app->session->setFlash('msg', 'Successful upload File and Process Integration will be Execute');
    Yii::$app->session->setFlash('msg_process', 'Process Integration in Execute');

    $tablelist = $this->getaccTables($data); 
    $result = $this->actionReadAccess($data, $tablelist);

    return $this->refresh();
}

public function actionReadAccess($data, $tables) {
    //... same connection setup ...

    // NEW LOOP FOR MULTIPLE QUERIES 
    foreach($tables as $tbl) {

        $query = 'SELECT TOP 100  * FROM ' . $tbl;
        $result = $connection->query($query)->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        print_r($result);            

    }

    $connection = NULL;

    return $result;
}
```